# Hazelcast Entry Processor: When objects affect objects in other maps

Tags: hazelcast

My example use case: 
I have an IMap with an old membership list (where members' addresses are stored as attributes of the member-object) and an IMap with valid addresses from an alternate member list. I know that my old member IMap has older information and the alternate address list has up-to-date address information (such as 4 digit zip code extensions).

I want to visit each member entry in the old member IMap and create a new address-object from the member-object. Each unique address will eventually be stored in a database, so I don't want duplicate address objects. I want to store each unique address in an IMap of valid addresses.

If I iterate over the old member IMap I get a `Class Not Found` exception when I try to put new address object into the new valid-addresses IMap.

If I'm creating new objects while visiting objects in one IMap, how do I collect them in another IMap?

Answer (score 0):

Entry Processors are intended to work only on the entry they're submitted to (the target of the executeOnKey() method).   This allows for a number of optimizations, as the entry processor runs on an operation thread dedicated to the partition holding the data.   If the Entry Processor was to access data in another partition, locks would be required and there is the possibility that a deadlock could occur.   If the other entry was on a different cluster node, this could adversely impact performance of the Entry Processor which should be a quick operation.

The executeOnKey method returns an Object; you could code your Entry Processor to return the new address object, and the client could then put this object to the appropriate map (which might be on a different cluster node).

This is also something that might be appropriate for Hazelcast Jet; Jet could use one map as a source and the other map as a sink and perform the appropriate operations as part of its pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to deal with this situation (effecting items in a second map) is to use an EventListener.

I implemented an EventListener for the old members map that adds an address-object to the address map if it doesn't already exist, whenever a member in the old members map is updated.

Jet does seem like a great way to deal with exactly this kind of process model, but I haven't implemented it yet to verify how it works in my use case.